# .NET Core's double trouble: 0.0 vs -0.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-4.8

I've moved some unit tests from .NET Framework to Core and with some sadness I discovered that some of the tests fail because the expected (`0.0`) does not match actual (`-0.0`).

After a short period of feeling sorry for myself (it was meant to be an easy move), I build the following test app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var d = 0d * -1;

    Console.WriteLine(d);
    Console.WriteLine(d == 0);
    Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { d }));
}
```

On Core the minus sign is preserved:

```
-0
True
{"d":-0.0}
```

On Framework minus zero looks like a zero:

```
0
True
{"d":0.0}
```

Why the change?

Comment: For completeness, the tests compared the string-representations, I guess?

Comment: never expect binary floating points to be _precise_.

Comment: @huysentruitw Correct, the tests compare json.

Comment: Maybe unit testing JSON is not the best idea

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be part of efforts described in [Floating-Point Parsing and Formatting improvements in .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/).

> Starting back with the .NET Core 2.1 release, we were making iterative improvements to the floating-point parsing and formatting code in .NET Core. Now, in .NET Core 3.0 Preview 3, we are nearing completion of this work and would like to share more details about these changes and some of the differences you might see in your applications.

And later:

> The summary of these changes is that (for double/float):
>
> `ToString()`, `ToString("G")`, and `ToString("R")` will now return the shortest roundtrippable string. This ensures that users end up with something that just works by default. An example of where it was problematic was `Math.PI.ToString()` where the string that was previously being returned (for `ToString()` and `ToString("G")`) was `3.14159265358979`; instead, it should have returned `3.1415926535897931`. The previous result, when parsed, returned a value which was internally off by 7 ULP (units in last place) from the actual value of `Math.PI`. This meant that it was very easy for users to get into a scenario where they would accidentally lose some precision on a floating-point value when the needed to serialize/deserialize it.
>
> (...)

This led me to GitHub and [Roundtrip string format for single/double doesn't roundtrip -0](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/9883) and [Update the double/float formatters to return the shortest roundtrippable string.](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/22040)

> https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13615
>
> No format specifier and just `G` are now equivalent to `R` and will return the shortest round-trippable string